# How do I liberate my mails from Lotus Notes for a better mail searching?

Tags: email, search, lotus-notes

in my work environment i'm forced to use the mail programm Lotus Notes from IBM. This old Lady is very slow and has its quirks. For example the search for specific emails is really bad compared to other mail solutions like gmail, thunderbird or outlook. It very rare to find the mail I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a way to export all the mail in a other mail tool for a better possibility to search.

Comment: Why not let somebody SHOW you how to search in Lotus Notes? I have to use Outlook since one year, and the search is MUCH worse than the one I was used to in Lotus Notes. 

The only thing is: You need to know how to do the RIGHT search. But for that we need the exact version of Lotus Notes you are using...

Comment: I'am using Lotus Notes in Version 8.5

Comment: Unfortunately there are 4 different ways to search (and yes, Notes sucks for having 4 instead of 1 search) and each gives you different results. First and best option is to use the "Search all Mail" field in the right upper corner of the screen: It does a fulltext- search in all mails. It works best, if a fulltext index is created for your mailfile - ask your admin to do so. If you just want to search the inbox / current folder: Use menu "View - Search this view". Third search: use Ctrl + F: It searches in the Folder / view that you are in at the moment, but only in visible columns.

Comment: 4th search would be: just start typing... this kind of search only searches the first sorted column... sometimes useful, but only if you know the exact beginning of the value you are searching for.